# Xcode 9.1 with fastlane not running headless

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcodebuild, fastlane

I'm running fastlane scan for our UI Tests on a iPad Air 2 iOS 11 simulator and my understanding from this article https://dzone.com/articles/new-xcuitest-features-with-xcode-9-hands-on-explor is that it should run headless automatically.

But it's launching the simulator every time.  Is there a xcargs that needs passed to make it run headless.

I don't see anything in the fastlane docs for scan that relates to headless.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the simulator application before you run `xcodebuild`. Conversely, if you want to see the simulator during tests, start the simulator beforehand via `Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Simulator`.